# Condicional if no toma la ruta que quiero FLASK

Tags: python, condiciones, flask

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras para un proyecto en FLASK, y me gustaria que cuando el carrito este vacío y el cliente pulsa el botón de 'Tramitar pedido', apareciese un flash por pantalla.El problema es que ejecuto un `if` para hacerlo y nunca toma el camino que quiero.Este seria el codigo para mostrar el carrito:

```
@app.route('/carrito')
def carrito_inicio():

sql = 'SELECT * FROM "carrito";'
conn = sqlite3.connect('database/mi_proyecto.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)

articulos = cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
    
return render_template('carrito.html', articulos=articulos)
```

Y este el código cuando el cliente pulsa '*Tramitar Pedido*':

```
@app.route('/tramitarPedido', methods=['GET','POST'])
def tramitarPedido():

conn = sqlite3.connect('database/mi_proyecto.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM carrito;')
total = cursor.fetchall()
if total == '':
    flash("El carrito esta vacio.")
    redirect('/carrito')
else:
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM carrito;')
    conn.commit()
    print("Pedido realizado!")
    
return redirect(url_for('retornarCliente'))
```

Y este es el html de mi carrito:

```
{% include 'header_carrito.html' %}
{% with messages= get_flashed_messages() %}

{% if messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {% for message in  messages %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}    
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% endwith %}
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <table class="table table-light">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Imagen</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Unidades</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for c in articulos %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img clas="img-thumbnail" width="100" src="uploads/{{c[4] }}" 
alt="">
                </td>
                <td>{{c[3] }}</td>
                <td>{{c[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{c[2] }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="return confirm(' Eliminar el articulo del carrito?')" 
class="btn btn-danger" href="/eliminar_articulo_pedido/{{c[0] }}">Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a href="/tramitarPedido" class="btn_tramitar_pedido btn btn-success">

        Tramitar Pedido

    </a>

{% include 'footer_carrito.html' %}
```

El problema que ocurre es que , aun teniendo el carrito vacío, el `if` toma la ruta del `else` y me realiza el pedido.

Comment: Claro, pero en este caso la expresion es correcta, ya que " total == '': "

Comment: Me sigue pasando al else, rey. Hasta he copiado y pegado el if que me has puesto por si acaso.

Comment: Buenas, no sé exactamente que dijo el otro, pero el fetchall() en caso de no encontrar nada ( no hay nada en el carrito entiendo) devuelve una lista vacía, por tanto, siguiendo esto `len(total)==0` sería la condición, referencia al que digo https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/

Comment: otra forma ya que python interprenta las listas vacias como false seria `if not total :`

Comment: En la documentacion *El método fetchAll() obtiene todas las filas (o todas las restantes) de un conjunto de resultados de consulta y devuelve una lista de tuplas. Si no hay más filas disponibles, devuelve una lista vacía*. Por que validas si es un string vacio? Debes validar la longitud de la lista (`len()`)!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda. Estoy aprendiendo Python y no habia tenido en cuenta la posibilidad de usar len() en esta funcion.